# Understand Makefile with two-step dependency calculation

Tags: makefile, build-automation, gnu, gnu-make, building

I wanted to build some C++ code. I've already had a magic Makefile that could calculate dependencies automaticaly, but I wanted to keep object files in separate directory. So the structure looks like:

- Makefile
- source/a/
- source/b/
- source/c/
- obj/

I was able to run Makefile that converted sources into objects using obj/ prefix, but things got messy when I wanted to backport dependency calculation.

The problem is that is almost all Makefile examples this is done in one step, creating .d from .cpp (`%.d: %.cpp`). I spent some time trying to understand Makefile and fix it with trials and errors. Finally I've got a working script:

```
DIRS := a b c
SOURCES := $(foreach dir,$(DIRS),$(wildcard source/$(dir)/*.cpp))
OBJECTS := $(patsubst %.cpp,obj/%.o,$(SOURCES))

obj/%.d: %.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    @$(CXX) -E $(CXXFLAGS) -MM -MP -MF $@ -MQ $(@:.d=.o) -MQ $@ $<

obj/%.o: %.cpp obj/%.d
    @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

project: $(OBJECTS)
    ...

-include $(OBJECTS:.o=.d)
```

But I'm still not sure why do I need to have separate steps for cpp->d and cpp&d -> o (or maybe I understand - but then I have no idea why most examples don't need this).

Comment: You do **not** need separate steps. You could combine them. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @Beta: I don't understand why all examples show transformation `%.d: %.cpp`. Target binary depends on object files (.o), not dependency files, yet in Makefile there are no rules for object files unless some dependency files exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the source files are `foo.cpp` and `bar.cpp`, and the headers are `foo.h` and `bar.h`, such that `foo.cpp` includes `foo.h` and `bar.h`, and `bar.cpp` includes `bar.h`.

You can have a simple makefile that does not involve dependency files at all:

```
project: $(OBJECTS)
    ...

%.o: %.cpp
    ...
```

Now if you modify `foo.cpp`, Make will rebuild `foo.o` (and `project`). If you modify `bar.cpp`, Make will rebuild `bar.o` (and `project`). If you modify a header, Make will do nothing, because Make doesn't know that the objects depend in any way upon the headers.

You can put in a rule for dependency files:

```
project: $(OBJECTS)
    ...

%.o: %.cpp
    ...

%.d:
    ...

-include *.d
```

Now Make will build and use the dependency files-- if you remember to tell it to. If you do that, Make will know that when you modify `foo.h` it must rebuild `foo.o`, and when you modify `bar.h` it must rebuild `foo.o` and `bar.o`.

Remembering to rebuild dependency files is a pain. It would be better to let Make do it. When must `foo.d` be rebuilt? Well, when `foo.cpp` is modified, certainly:

```
project: $(OBJECTS)
    ...

%.o: %.cpp
    ...

%.d: %.cpp
    ...

-include *.d
```

But `foo.d` must also be rebuilt when any of the other prerequisites of `foo.o` (i.e. `foo.h` or `bar.h`) has been modified. I haven't spelled out the commands in the rules (and I can't make much sense of the command in your `%.d` rule), but a simple rule will build a `foo.d` that looks like this:

```
foo.o: foo.cpp foo.h bar.h
```

It is possible to write a command that will produce a `foo.d` that looks like this:

```
foo.o: foo.cpp foo.h bar.h

foo.d: foo.cpp foo.h bar.h
```

There are more sophisticated methods, but this is enough for today.

As to *why* many example makefiles share a certain sub-optimal feature, it's because people copy each others' makefiles without rigorously examining or understanding every feature.